# Metal Command Buffer optimal for blur then display of MTLTexture

Tags: swift, gpu, metal

I have the following code which blurs a MTLTexture and then renders it to a MTKView, however, is the ordering of the command buffer optimal?

blur is a Metal Performance Shader, The compute shader just writes the texture, it's a simple pass-through.

```
var t: MTLTexture? = mtlLayer.currentSceneDrawable?.texture


    let drawableTexture: MTLTexture? = metalView.currentDrawable!.texture

    let commandBuffer: MTLCommandBuffer = commandQueue.makeCommandBuffer()!


    blur.encode(commandBuffer: commandBuffer, inPlaceTexture: &t!, fallbackCopyAllocator: nil)

    let commandEncoder = commandBuffer.makeComputeCommandEncoder()!
    commandEncoder.setComputePipelineState(pipelineState)
    commandEncoder.setTexture(t, index: 0)
    commandEncoder.setTexture(drawableTexture, index: 1)
    commandEncoder.dispatchThreadgroups(threadgroupsPerGrid, threadsPerThreadgroup: threadsPerThreadgroup)
    commandEncoder.endEncoding()

    commandBuffer.present(metalView.currentDrawable!)
    metalView.draw()

    commandBuffer.commit();
    commandBuffer.waitUntilCompleted()
```

Comment: Why are you not using `encode(commandBuffer:sourceTexture:destinationTexture:)` to encode directly to the drawable texture? Do you need to keep the blurred image for anything else? If you don't want to blur directly to the destination, then why are you using a compute shader to copy the texture? Why not a blit encoder or a draw?

Comment: @kenThomases - Doh! Thank you!

Comment: Hi Ken, please move your comment to a formal answer, so that Chris can accept it and avoid yet one more question that appears listed as not answered. Thanks for your contributions, which I really appreciate.